# What does the "More Columns than Column Names" error mean?

Tags: r, csv, read.table, import-from-csv

I'm trying to read in a .csv file from the IRS and it doesn't appear to be formatted in any weird way.

I'm using the `read.table()` function, which I have used several times in the past but it isn't working this time; instead, I get this error:

```
data_0910<-read.table("/Users/blahblahblah/countyinflow0910.csv",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,colClasses="character")

Error in read.table("/Users/blahblahblah/countyinflow0910.csv",  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Why is it doing this?

For reference, the `.csv` files can be found at:

http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-County-to-County-Migration-Data-Files

(The ones I need are under the county to county migration .csv section - either inflow or outflow.)

Answer (score 24):

It uses commas as separators.  So you can either set `sep=","` or just use `read.csv`:

```
x <- read.csv(file="http://www.irs.gov/file_source/pub/irs-soi/countyinflow1011.csv")
dim(x)
## [1] 113593      9
```

The error is caused by spaces in some of the values, and unmatched quotes.  There are no spaces in the header, so `read.table` thinks that there is one column.  Then it thinks it sees multiple columns in some of the rows.  For example, the first two lines (header and first row):

```
State_Code_Dest,County_Code_Dest,State_Code_Origin,County_Code_Origin,State_Abbrv,County_Name,Return_Num,Exmpt_Num,Aggr_AGI
00,000,96,000,US,Total Mig - US & For,6973489,12948316,303495582
```

And unmatched quotes, for example on line 1336 (row 1335) which will confuse `read.table` with the default `quote` argument (but not `read.csv`):

```
01,089,24,033,MD,Prince George's County,13,30,1040
```

Comment: @user3084629: There are also unmatched quotes. Read more carefully in ?read.table

Answer (score 5):

you have have strange characters in your heading # % -- or ,

Answer (score 3):

For the Germans:

you have to change your decimal commas into a Full stop in your csv-file (in Excel:File -> Options -> Advanced -> "Decimal seperator") , then the error is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data (e.g. tsv extension) it may use tab as separators, so you may try `sep = '\t'` with `read.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

This error can get thrown if your data frame has `sf` geometry columns.